# PGLOADER: --with "quote identifiers": column ""invoiceNo"" of relation "Order" does not exist

Tags: database, postgresql, double-quotes, pgloader

Getting the following error when I try to do:

```
pgloader --with "quote identifiers" "mysql://..." "postgresql://..."
```

I am getting this error:

```
What I am doing here?

Database error 42703: column ""invoiceNo"" of relation "Order" does not exist
CONTEXT: PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 6 at FOR over SELECT rows
QUERY: 
DO $$
DECLARE
  n integer := 0;
  r record;
BEGIN
  FOR r in
       SELECT 'select '
               || trim(trailing ')'
                  from replace(pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid),
                               'nextval', 'setval'))
               || ', (select greatest(max(' || quote_ident(a.attname) || '), (select seqmin from pg_sequence where seqrelid = ('''
               || pg_get_serial_sequence(quote_ident(nspname) || '.' || quote_ident(relname), quote_ident(a.attname)) || ''')::regclass limit 1), 1) from only '
               || quote_ident(nspname) || '.' || quote_ident(relname) || '));' as sql
         FROM pg_class c
              JOIN pg_namespace n on n.oid = c.relnamespace
              JOIN pg_attribute a on a.attrelid = c.oid
              JOIN pg_attrdef d on d.adrelid = a.attrelid
                                 and d.adnum = a.attnum
                                 and a.atthasdef
        WHERE relkind = 'r' and a.attnum > 0
              and pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid) ~ '^nextval'
              and c.oid in (select oid from reloids)
  LOOP
    n := n + 1;
    EXECUTE r.sql;
  END LOOP;

  PERFORM pg_notify('seqs', n::text);
END;
$$;
```

Does it have to do something with the double quotes here maybe: `column ""invoiceNo"" of`? I am not sure how to fix this. When I do the same command without the  `--with "quote identifiers"`, the error is gone - but then my tables aren't in camel case, which is not what I want.